# SQL Server SPID

Tags: sql-server

Fellow devs,

From SQL Server Management Studio, I can see that a lot of SPIDs are still present eventhough the application which has triggered them has already used and closed the query. What could be causing this?

Any avenues for me to look at concerning this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

connection pooling by the client driver is most likely the cause.
-don